# MongoRepository custom Id

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have the following MongoDB Repository

```
public interface TeamRepository extends MongoRepository<Team, TeamId> {
    ....
}
```

And the following classes:

```
public abstract class DbId implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private final String id;

    public DbId(final String id) { this.id = id;}

    public String getId() { return id;}
}

public class TeamId extends DbId {

    public TeamId(final String id) {
        super(id)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have like a custom id for the repository (I have MongoRepository instead of something like MongoRepository). But, when I am trying to save a Team object, I get an error saying that MongoDB does not know how to generate DBId. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb (or any database) would not know how to generate a string ID without you informing it what the value of the string is.

The default `@Id` is a string representation of [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), which can be auto-generated by MongoDB. If you are changing the type of string ObjectId to a class, then at least the class needs to define:

** Conversion to string (serialisable), for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(
            "TeamID[uniqueString=%s]",
            myUniqueString);
}
```

** How to generate the Id.

You can define a method in your TeamRepository i.e. `save()` to specify how your string can be generated. Alternatively you can check out

https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-auto-sequence-id-example/

Where the example specify `getNextSequenceId()` to generate `NumberLong` custom id. Hopefully that guides you to your answer.